# Adding include paths for C++ project in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I just started using Visual Studio Code with C/C++ extensions and I want to include non-system header `C:/Libraries/sq.h` located outside of my project directory. I added its path to `c_cpp_properties.json` file so Intellisense can find the header:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "${vcpkgRoot}/x64-windows/include",
            "C:/Libraries"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
        "compilerPath": "C:/Programs/MinGW/bin/g++.exe",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
    }
],
```

Unfortunately, the build task configuration is not aware of `C:/Libraries` path, so I had to add it to `tasks.json` too:

```
      "args": ["-I", "C:/Libraries", "-g0", "-o", "hellovscode", "main.cpp"],
```

Is there any way to avoid duplicating the include paths? Are there tools, which can generate and maintain these configuration files?

Comment: There isn't, unfortunately, short of installing some other extension which may let you specify both in one place.

Comment: You can use normal Visual Studio. It also makes it possible to avoid duplication of settings when dealing with multiple projects / solutions.